# Lorentz similarity transforms

Tags: field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I am reading Peskin-Schröder, p. 36. Here is what I don't understand: They define a similarity transform in the coordinate space as:

$$x^{\mu} \rightarrow x'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} x^{\nu}$$

Then their field transform becomes:

$$\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) = \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$$

How is it that $\Lambda$ got inverted? How to see (prove) it? There are also the derivative and double derivative of the field, but I think if I get how the previous step is done, I will be able to figure out those myself.

Comment: to go with Schirmers answer below, in the expression $\phi(x)$ \rightarrow $\phi'(x)$ has a typo - the second instance of $x$ has a missing apostrophe; it should be $\phi(x)$ \rightarrow $\phi'(x')$.

Comment: You're welcome! Though Schirmer should get most of the credit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the transformation of fields 
$$\phi \to \phi'\tag {1}$$
induced by a  coordinate transformation
$$x \to x' = \Lambda x \tag {2}$$
 is such that *if we simultaneously change coordinates and fields, then nothing changes*.

In other words, the right hand side of (1) must be defined in order to fulfill
$$\phi'(x') = \phi (x)\:.$$
Since, from (2), $$x =\Lambda^{-1}x'\:,$$
we are committed to define $\phi'$ as the function
$$\phi'(y) := \phi (\Lambda^{-1}y)$$
for every spacetime point $y $.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Following what you wrote it has to be $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x)=\phi'(\Lambda^{-1}x')$... Do you mean, that there is an extra step: $\phi'(\Lambda^{-1}x') := \phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$?

Comment: Just a trivial typo, thanks. I have corrected the text of my answer now.

Answer (score 5):

$\phi^{\prime}$ should be a function of the transformed coordinate, but is otherwise no different than $\phi$

So, $\phi(x)$ needs to be transformed to a function of $x^{\prime}$.  We have $x^{\prime}  = \Lambda x$, so $x = \Lambda^{-1} x^{\prime}$, and we then have $\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}) = \phi(\Lambda^{-1}x^{\prime}) = \phi(x)$